# How do I write a query that bridges two tables?

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have two tables, two differently name columns in these tables match up.

```
Table A:
a
b
c
d
e

Table B:
f
g
h
```

I need to display a grid view of e, g and h, Joining the tables together based on the f and b matching up. I know how to fill a grid view based on a query, its just the query itself I'm after.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29. Union queries don't join tables, they "join" different queries so as to produce a single result set.

Comment: You'll have to show an example of what you want the end result to be because I still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: @MarcB http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all of your columns are uniquely named, and you are joining two different tables, no aliasing is necessary, and you don't need to fully qualify the column names.

The SQL term you are looking for is a JOIN.  In this case, it sounds like you want an inner join (there are many ways to write them).

```
SELECT 
    e,g,h
FROM 
    TableA 
    INNER JOIN TableB 
        ON b = f
```

Answer (score 3):

You used the very words in your question: "*joining the tables together based on the f and b matching up*".

```
SELECT e,g,h FROM `Table A` JOIN `Table B` ON f=b
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be:

```
SELECT e,g,h FROM Table A, Table B WHERE Table A.b == Table B.f
```

That's the JOIN I would use. It may need tweaked depending on what your variables are.

Sorry, this works for SQL not MYSQL.